# How can I organise program, which should have non-blocking connection on Python?

Tags: python, sockets

My question is next:
I want to write a program which should connect to the same program on the other machine, and both this program should exchange some information. I can't set up non-blocking connection. How can it be?

Comment: Cannot understand the problem. Try to be clearer. Which is the problem? You write a socket server and a socket client? Do they connect? Anyway you may want to take a look at Twsited Perspective Brocker: http://twistedmatrix.com/documents/current/core/howto/pb-usage.html

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the asyncore library: http://docs.python.org/library/asyncore.html

And specifically, the asynchat examples: http://docs.python.org/library/asynchat.html#asynchat.async_chat

It should do exactly what you need here.

Answer (score 0):

The most simple solution to have a non-blocking socket in Python is just to use the [setblocking() method](http://docs.python.org/library/socket.html#socket.socket.setblocking) on the socket. Something like this:

```
import socket

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.setblocking(0)

# bind, accept or connect stuff

s.recv(100) # will not block and if no data available a "socket.error"
            # exception will be raised
```

You may also want to take a look at [settimeout()](http://docs.python.org/library/socket.html#socket.socket.settimeout)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to pass Python objects, you can "serialize" them with the [pickle](http://docs.python.org/library/pickle.html) module and send them through sockets, as described in other answers.